# Effect of conductivity on time constant

Tags: instrumentation

Usually the governing equation for a thermometer is given by,

$$\frac{m c_v}{h\;A_s}\dfrac{dT(t)}{dt}+ T(t) = T_\infty$$

Now for a problem the thermal conductivity of the thermometer bulb is also given. I am not sure if I have to account for the thermal conductivity in the problem. How would conductivity affect the given equation?
To be more precise what would be the effect on time constant for the system as my end goal is obtaining the time constant.

Comment: IMHO, in the case of the bulb thermometer, you are not using conductivity but convection. Therefore you need to reconsider the application of the equation.

Comment: Consider modeling a temperature sensor as a sphere having a thermal conductivity of 91 W/m-K, a
density of 8900 kg/m3, and a specific heat of 444 J/kg-K. The sensor is in an environment where the
heat transfer coefficient is 100 W/m2-K. Determine the maximum allowable diameter of the sensor if
the 90% response time to a step-change in the fluid temperature, T∞, must be: a. 10 s; b. 1 s and c.
0.01 s.   This is the original question for better perspective. I'm just not sure if the conductivity is given to throw me off or is it actually needed for solution

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first governing equation you give above uses the [lumped-capacitance assumption](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lumped-element_model); in other words, the thermal conductivity is assumed to be high enough, or the diameter small enough, or the external heat transfer slow enough, that the entire bulb is essentially at a single temperature $T(t)$. This is a fantastically useful simplifying assumption—as long as the [Biot number](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Biot_number) is suitably small.

It sounds like you've now been tasked with analyzing the situation without making this assumption. With spatial temperature variation now an option inside the sphere, we have the [conduction heat equation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Heat_equation)

$$k\nabla^2 T(r,t)=c\rho\frac{\partial T(r,t)}{\partial t};$$

$$-k\frac{\partial T(r=r_0,t)}{\partial r}-h[T(r=r_0,t)-T_\infty]=0,$$

where $k$ is the thermal conductivity, $\nabla^2$ is the [Laplacian](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Laplace_operator#Three_dimensions) (in spherical coordinates, where I've assumed axisymmetry), $T$ is the temperature, $r$ is the distance from the sphere center, $t$ is time, $c$ is the specific heat, $\rho$ is the density, $r_0$ is the sphere radius, and $h$ is the heat transfer coefficient at the surface.

The first equation describes conduction inside the sphere, and the second provides a boundary condition that you'll need for the solution (in addition to the initial conditions).

Multiple heat transfer textbooks and handbooks describe the details of the solution, including Incropera & DeWitt, *Fundamentals of Heat and Mass Transfer*, §5.6, Radial Systems with Convection. The full solution contains an infinite series with a variety of time constants; the first (dominant) term has a time constant proportional to the time over the [Fourier number](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fourier_number), the Fourier number being $kt/c\rho r_0^2$.

Does this all make sense?

Comment: Except for the last few lines where you talked about the Fourier number, I've understood the explanation. Guess I will need to look into Heat transfer books. Thank you very much for the answer